# Updateable contract design: Database contract only accessible through setters and getters?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, database, design-patterns

Hey I'm designing a Dapp that has a database contract and a contract with the logic side. The only way I can see of making this work is through having the logic contract make a call to a getter or setter in the database contract for every value it needs. This seems like a very expensive design. Is there a better way to access this data, using libraries or some other way?

Comment: This is a personal area of interest of mine. I'm not sure I can articulate and brief answer in this site's Q&A format because it's a big topic. At the risk of sounding inappropriate, I'd be willing to switch to private message channel of some kind to explore your goals and help you choose from different macro-level approaches you might consider. Possibly share some reasonably well documented simple solutions or some code for more generalized collections contracts that do that sort of thing.

Comment: Yaa I'd love to work through some examples, do you have a good idea for a message channel?

Comment: We can set up a room in appear.in. Sunday afternoon is ideal for me. Mountain time.

Comment: Ok great, I'll be online around then.

Comment: `delegatecall` is a more efficient and extensible option IMHO

Comment: Yaa I think that link solves the question.